# diff for git rebase dry-run

Tags: git, diff, git-rebase, git-diff

I want to see what parts of a *topic* branch are already included into an *upstream* branch, and what possible conflicts can arise on rebase.

It should be a kind of dry-run for git-rebase that shows a diff between the *topic* and the *upstream*, excluding the changes that don't connect with the *topic*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A one solution is to apply diff on the diffs. The idea is:

1. get diff between *forkpoint* and *topic*
2. get diff between *upstream* and *topic*
3. compare these diffs

`git-diff-rebase` script file:

```
#!/bin/bash

upstream="$1"
topic="$2"

root=$( git rev-parse --show-toplevel )
forkpoint=$( git merge-base $upstream $topic )

if [ -z "$forkpoint" ] ; then
  echo "Merge base is not found" 1>&2
  exit 1
fi

# list of the changed files (space separated)
files=$( git -C "$root" diff --name-only $forkpoint $topic | paste -s -d ' ' )

diff -t --tabsize=4 -W $(tput cols) -y --left-column \
  <( git -C "$root" diff $forkpoint $topic ) \
  <( git -C "$root" diff $upstream $topic -- $files ) \
  | grep -vP '(^ *> )' \
  # skip changes that do not interfere with topic (empty left part)
```

NB: this script should not work for the files with spaces in name.

Usage: `git-diff-rebase master topic | less`

How to interpret the result:

- `* * <`     — (empty right part) already included into *upstream*
- `+ * |   *` — (identic text) already included into *upstream*
- `- * | + *` — conflict
- `+ * | - *` — possible conflict
- `+ * (` — (empty right part) no conflict, absent in the upstream
- `- * (` — (empty right part) no conflict, present in the upstream
- `* (` — (empty right part) present in both topic and upstream

Where `*` is placeholder for any text.

Answer (score 2):

> I want to see what parts of a *topic* branch already included into *upstream* branch, and what possible conflicts can arise on rebase.

Correct me if I'm wrong, but it sounds like you want to get a patch with just the conflicting changes contained in `topic`, if any.

Since a rebase is a kind of merge, I think the easiest way to do that would be to do a merge without creating a commit (you could call it a "*dry merge*") and inspect the diff of the *unmerged* (i.e. conflicting) files:

```
git checkout topic
git merge upstream --no-commit --no-ff
```

Once you have the merged files from `develop` in your working directory, all you have to do is inspect the diff of any unmerged files:

```
git diff --diff-filter=U
```

Comment: Excellent recipe to view the conflicts only, thanks! It is need to add `git merge --abort` and revert the original branch after all. But I need to know what the parts of _topic_ are already included into the _upstream_ to know should the _topic_ be deleted or rebased and kept.

Answer (score 1):

One approach here is to make a copy of your target branch (git checkout -b tmpbranch), do the rebase there, and then diff that against the unmodified branch.

Comment: NB: on rebase you need to resolve conflicts. It is an overkill for dry-run.

Comment: That depends on the nature of the dry-run (and, on the extent of the conflicts -- which, in turn, reflect your coding and commit practices).